# How to loop through the whole text file?

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

i need your help!, i am working on a script that, takes the string from a text file that grabs a value from the text file 20 characters.

Now i want to add spaces in front of character that was grabbed from the text file. However, i want to apply it to the whole text file.

For example:

Text 1 A (input):

```
01253654758965475896N12345
012536547589654758960011223325
```

(output):

```
(added 10 spaces in front)01253654758965475896   N12345
(added 10 spaces in front)01253654758965475896   0011223325
```

The idea is to loop through them, i added 10x spaces in front of and then also added spaces after  01253654758965475896.

Here is my code:

```
class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int acc = 1;
            string calcted = (acc++).ToString().PadLeft(20, '0');
            string ft_space = new string(' ', 12);

            string path = Console.ReadLine();
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadToEnd()) != null)
                {

                        string px = s;
                        string cnd = s.Substring(0, 16);
                        string cdr = cnd;

                        px = ft_space + cdr;

                        Console.Write("Enter Location:");
                        string pt1 = Console.ReadLine();
                        if (!File.Exists(pt1))
                        {

                            using (TextWriter sw = File.CreateText(pt1))
                            {
                                sw.Write(px);
                            }

                        }
                    } Console.ReadKey();


            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use ReadLine() instead of ReadToEnd().

Comment: In your example. Why did you add spaces after `01253654758965475896` but you did not add similar spaces to the other line?

Comment: Thank for the interest, i forgot to add the spaces, i updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, first change `ReadToEnd` to `ReadLine`.

`ReadToEnd` will read all the file, `ReadLine` will read one line every loop iteration.

Then, since you want 20 characters and not 16, you need to change `s.Substring(0, 16)` to `s.Substring(0, 20)`.

After that you need to obtain the rest of the line, so that will be `s.Substring(20)`.

You then need to concatenate all the parts together like this:

```
string result = spaces10 + first_part + spaces3 + second_part;
```

Another problem is that you just write the first line since you check if the file exists every time on the loop and you don't write the line if the file exists.

Here is how your code will look after such changes (and others):

```
string spaces10 = new string(' ', 10);

string spaces3 = new string(' ', 3);

string input_file = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Write("Enter Location:");
string output_file = Console.ReadLine();

using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(input_file))
{
    using (TextWriter sw = File.CreateText(output_file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string first_part = line.Substring(0, 20);

            string second_part = line.Substring(20);

            string result = spaces10 + first_part + spaces3 + second_part;

            sw.WriteLine(result);

        }
    } 
}

Console.ReadKey();
```